# Is there fast way to clear certain pixels of a bitmap in android?

Tags: android, bitmap

In my android app I do image manipulation. One of the steps, I need to quickly set certain pixels of the image to fully transparent.

The way I do this, is I run a BFS algorithm from the center of the image, and it creates a sparsearray of coordinates of the pixels that should remain. Then I do a double for loop and iterate through the entire bitmap and set pixels transparent if they are not in the sparse array.

Is there a faster way to do this? Possibly something like this (pseudo code):

```
bitmap.setpixelstatic(x, y);
bitmap.setpixelstatic(x+1, y);
...

bitmap.setColorofNonstaticpixel(Color.Transparent);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start with making an arrangement to your algorithm. It is good to use a sparse matrice to detect the coordinates of the pixels that should remain but instead of determining the coordinates that is not going to change, you must determine the ones that are going to change thus you will only access to the needed pixels, not making a square looping. Just like this:

Your way;

```
for i 1 to width
    for j 1 to height
        if pixel at [i, j] going to remain than
            sparse.push(i, j)
for i 1 to width
    for j 1 to height
        if [i, j] not in sparse than modify
```

You improved algorithm;

```
for i 1 to width
    for j 1 to height
        if pixel at [i, j] NOT GOING TO REMAIN than
            sparse.push(i, j)
for each pixelCoordinates in sparse
    modify pixel at [pixelCoordinates.i, pixelCoordinates.j]
```

I wish this helps.